# Set only buy alerts for tradingview Strategy alert

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have set alerts for my tradingview strategy from the strategy tester window and it works fine. I receive an alert whenever a new position is opened or an open position is closed. however, i want to only receive alerts only when a new position is opened. is there a way i can achieve that?

Comment: Please show us your code so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just added the alert line right before entry

```
if condition and strategy.position == 0
    alert(syminfo.ticker, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    strategy.entry(id, direction, qty, limit, stop, oca_name, oca_type, comment, 
    alert_message)
```

then in the create new alert box, I selected "alert() functions only" instead of "order fills"